# How to use absolute path in twig functions

Tags: symfony, routes, twig

I have an application with Symfony2 (2.2). When I want to send a mail, I'm having trouble with the paths, which are all relative paths and obviously aren't working inside emails

for rendering the paths I'm using:

```
<a href="{{ path('route_name', {'param' : value}) }}">A link</a>
```

and for assets:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundle/myname/img/image.gif') }}" alt="Title"/>
```

The previous examples work fine but the paths are relative therefore I need to append the domain. I can do something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com{{ path('route_name', {'param' => param1}) }}">A link</a>
```

but this is not the best solution for my problem, as I have different domains.

I found the solution for paths with the `url` function but I still need a solution for assets.

Comment: For the assets: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#controlling-the-url-used

Comment: that work for images i've readed the doc i can't find anything about images

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**For Symfony 2.7 and newer**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769933/2240272) answer here.

**1st working option**

```
{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/search.png') }}
```

**2nd working option - preferred**

Just made a quick test with a clean new Symfony copy. There is also [another option](https://github.com/fabpot/symfony/commit/df8d94e33c8b774732984066fce3dae81d5435c4) which combines scheme and httpHost:

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/search.png') }}
{# outputs #}
{# http://localhost/Symfony/web/bundles/acmedemo/css/demo.css  #}
```

Comment: you can shortcut this to {{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost ~ asset('images/foo.jpg') }} ah didnt see your update :D

Comment: This answer seems to be somewhat outdated. See the answer from Neto form Sep 24 '15.

Answer (score 139):

Symfony 2.7 has a new **absolute_url** which can be used to generate the absolute url.
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component#template-function-changes

It will work on those both cases or a path string:

```
<a href="{{ absolute_url(path('route_name', {'param' : value})) }}">A link</a>
```

and for assets:

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('bundle/myname/img/image.gif')) }}" alt="Title"/>
```

Or for any string path

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url('my/absolute/path') }}" alt="Title"/>
```

on those tree cases you will end up with an absolute URL like

```
http://www.example.com/my/absolute/path
```

Comment: This seems to be the most up-to-date answer so far.

Comment: Symfony 2.3.* has an `url` helper

Comment: This is the best answer for V3.0 +

Comment: Hi @Axel, that is expected. The CLI doesn't know what your domain name is. However, you can configure your request context, here is how https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/request_context.html

Answer (score 53):

From [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html):
Absolute URLs for assets were introduced in Symfony 2.5.

If you need absolute URLs for assets, you can set the third argument (or the absolute argument) to true:

Example:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png', absolute=true) }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```

Comment: yeah is for new developments :|

Answer (score 27):

[Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049712/how-to-use-absolute-path-in-twig-functions/25208267#25208267) seems to work fine for now, but please note that generating absolute urls using twig's `asset` function is now deprecated:

> DEPRECATED - Generating absolute URLs with the Twig asset() function
>   was deprecated in 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Please use
>   absolute_url() instead.

Here's the official announcement: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component#template-function-changes

You have to use the `absolute_url` twig function:

```
{# Symfony 2.6 #}
{{ asset('logo.png', absolute = true) }}

{# Symfony 2.7 #}
{{ absolute_url(asset('logo.png')) }}
```

It is interesting to note that it also works with `path` function:

```
{{ absolute_url(path('index')) }}
```

Comment: FYI absolute_url works on 4.3, this should be accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

You probably want to use the `assets_base_urls` configuration.

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls:
            http:   [http://www.example.com]
            ssl:   [https://www.example.com]
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets

---

Note that the configuration is different since [Symfony 2.7](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets):

```
framework:
    # ...
    assets:
        base_urls:
            - 'http://cdn.example.com/'
```

Comment: I updated the URL and noticed that the code changed too. I took the liberty to update your answer. Feel free to revert the changes.

Comment: @A.L thanks for the edit, I wasn't aware of the change.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to have `http://test.example` and `https://production.example`. Then hard coding the URL is a bad idea.
I would suggest this:

```
{{app.request.scheme ~ '://' ~ app.request.host ~ asset('bundle/myname/img/image.gif')}}
```

Comment: You can override configs for test and dev environments (config.yml, config_dev.yml, ...), so that's not an issue.

Comment: always renders http for me - even in https

Answer (score 4):

This is working at least in newer Symfony projects:

```
{{ absolute_url(asset('bundle/myname/img/image.gif')) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundle/myname/img/image.gif', null, true) }}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional info to generate absolute URL using a command (to send an email for instance)

In a command, `{{ absolute_url(path('index')) }}` is not working out of the box.

You will need to add the additional configuration shown in antongorodezkiy's answer.

But in case you don't want to change the configuration because you are not sure how it could impact the whole app, you can configure the router in the command.

Here is the doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/request_context.html

Here is the code :

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
// ...

class DemoCommand extends Command
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->router = $router;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $context = $this->router->getContext();
        $context->setHost('example.com');
        $context->setScheme('https');
        $context->setBaseUrl('my/path');

        $url = $this->router->generate('route-name', ['param-name' => 'param-value']);
        // ...
    }
}
```

To generate the URL in the Twig template

```
<a href="{{ absolute_url(path(...)) }}"></a>
```

You can fetch the HOST and SCHEME from your env file

```
$context = $this->router->getContext();
$context->setHost($_ENV['NL_HOST']);
$context->setScheme($_ENV['NL_SCHEME']);
```

Just define the variable in .env and .env.local files

```
NL_HOST=mydomain.com
NL_SCHEME=https
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following advice from the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html to get absolute urls in emails:

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: 'example.org'
    router.request_context.scheme: 'https'
```