# How do I generate full URLs for optimised assets using Assetic in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I want to include full asset URLs in my page templates, mainly so the Behat failed test page grabs still display properly.  I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049712/how-to-use-absolute-path-in-twig-functions), which suggests using `absolute_url()` as of 2.7, however I'm using the {% stylesheets %} or {% image %} tags to filter my assets.

Can anyone advise if there's a better way than doing something like this...

```
{% image
'@AcemBundle/Resources/public/imgs/logo.jpg'
output='compiled/imgs/logo.jpg' %}
<img src="{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ asset_url }}" alt="Logo"/>
{% endimage %}
```

... ?

#### Updated

Added full {% image %} tag I'm using.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/assets/img/logo.png') }}">
```

Comment: But does that apply the filters as the {% image %} tag does?  I'll update me question to demonstrate how I'm using it.

Comment: If you use it as my code you dont need the {% image %} tag.

Comment: But I want to apply the filter to the image (which I missed off my example).  This example doesn't apply the filter, does it?