# Slim3 + Twig > Full URL for href links instead of relative ones.

Tags: php, twig, slim-3

I'm using Slim3 together with Twig. Now when I'm trying to "build" a link with the `path_for` helper in a twig template I don't get the full URL like `https://domain.tld/path/to/something`, instead it's just `/path/to/something`. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049712/how-to-use-absolute-path-in-twig-functions

Comment: don't think so, since this isn't a Twig issue really. I think it's more of a Slim router issue. Might be wrong so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've somewhat hacked the [slim/twig-view](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) extension to get it working. So within the TwigExtension.php I've changed

```
public function pathFor($name, $data = [], $queryParams = [], $appName = 'default') 
{
    return $this->router->pathFor($name, $data, $queryParams);
}
```

to

```
public function pathFor($name, $data = [], $queryParams = [], $appName = 'default')
{
    if (getenv('APP_HOST') != '') {
        return getenv('APP_HOST') . $this->router->pathFor($name, $data, $queryParams);
    }
    return $this->router->pathFor($name, $data, $queryParams);
}
```

I **bet** that there's a more elegant way to get this fixed. But currently that fixes *my* problem.

This of course requires to use an .env file together with library that makes the variables accessible via `getenv()`. For that I use [PHPDotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv). You could tackle this from all sorts of angles, I guess.

I still don't know why @Scriptonomy's solution doesn't work. It really should. But in my case it just doesn't ... Comments as to where I might have screwed up are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **Twig** helper **path_for** to return the full URL rather than just an absolute one, you need to set the **basePath** property on the router.

Grab the container:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
```

Grab the router:

```
$router= $container->get('router');
```

Set the basePath:

```
$router->setBasePath('https://domain.tld');
```

Comment: `$container = $app->getContainer();
$router = $container->get('router');
$router->setBasePath(getenv('APP_HOST'));`

That didn't do anything for some reason. Links are still relative in the source of the page.

Changed `$container->get('settings')` to `$container->get('router')`. Since 'settings' doesn't contain the setBasePath method.

Now I don't get any errors, but nothing changed either. :P

Comment: btw. managing _vital_ data with an `.env` file, thus getenv (which works, checked with var_dump).